# Not able to Print International character

Tags: javascript, node.js, thermal-printer

I am using node-thermal-printer node module to print some Vietnamese text. I printed
"Thành phố Hồ Chí Minh" to test it. but it print "?" at few places, as shown in image attached. Any help would be appreciated to resolve this. I also used different characterset like **WPC1258_VIETNAMESE** mentioned in documentation but things are still same.
I am using following node module https://github.com/Klemen1337/node-thermal-printer

[image]

Comment: Provide your simple code, it helps everybody easy to debug. Try use `raw` data instead of `unraw` text.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with using buffer data instead of raw text, and it seem working fine. But I did not tested with real printer.

Run below snippet code, my output will be like:

```
Thành phố Hồ Chí Minh
------------------------------------------------
```

```
const ThermalPrinter = require("node-thermal-printer").printer;
const PrinterTypes = require("node-thermal-printer").types;

(async () => {
  let printer = new ThermalPrinter({
    type: PrinterTypes.STAR,
    interface: 'tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    characterSet: 'SLOVENIA',
    removeSpecialCharacters: false,
    lineCharacter: "-",
    options: {
      timeout: 1000
    }
  });

  printer.setBuffer(Buffer.from("Thành phố Hồ Chí Minh\n"));
  printer.drawLine();

  console.log(printer.getText());

  // I do not have any real printer
  // try {
  //   await printer.execute();
  //   console.log("Print success.");
  // } catch (error) {
  //   console.error("Print error:", error);
  // }
})();
```

Comment: It print **Th├ánh phß╗æ Hß╗ô Ch├¡ Minh** for me. seems not working yet.

Comment: Will it depend upon any font or language of system or mode of printer ? Also which version node-thermal-printer you are using?

Comment: @SteadyReader I am using `node-thermal-printer` version `4.1.0`.

Comment: I am also using the same.

Comment: So is it logging for you correctly as you mentioned ? will it depend on anything else ?

Comment: @SteadyReader I am testing on Ubuntu 16.04, what is your?

Comment: In my case it is Windows 10.

Comment: @SteadyReader :-? What is your nodejs version? My version is `v11.12.0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200699/discussion-between-hoangdv-and-steadyreader).